# How to Ignore Properties at the Class Level for .Net Core Web API Bind Model

Tags: json, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there a way to specify included or excluded properties for a complex type in a request model like JsonInclude? I would think having to write a POCO for each request and having to add validation attributes for each property on each of those POCOs would be a nightmare.

```
public class RegisterUserRequest
{
    //Ignore all other properties including their requirement attributes
    [JsonInclude("FirstName,LastName,Username,Password")] 
    public User user { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PasswordConfirmation { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DefaultContractResolver

The given two links can help you.

https://www.niceonecode.com/question/20711/newtonsoft-json-ignore-property-dynamically-during-serialization

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm

Also, you can cover basic ignore property when ReadOnly, Empty, etc. conditions in the given link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Comment: Thanks, the basic ignore conditions will work.  I can use [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)] and set default value when instantiating

Comment: @JGDev, you can also use the DefaultContractResolver to dynamic serialization. Is there any problem at here?

Comment: no and that would be ideal.  I didn’t see where the DefaultContractResolver did that in this case.  Do you have an example.